# Creating a Batch File to Set Path in Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have installed JDK 1.7.0_17 on my windows7 32 bit machine and created a batch file set java path but it doesn't work.

I have installed jdk under c:\program files.... and need to run java from E: and created batch file under E:\ as follows:

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin";
```

I got the following exception whenever I run the .bat file.

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: any specific requirement for doing this through set path.. why you are not setting environment variable? Can you post your bat file

Comment: I cant see an "exception" in your question... please be more specific, exactly what happens??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin";%path%
```

Comment: Thanks,I have added environment variable and recreate batch as you mentioned, now its works

Answer (score 0):

After this `set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin";`add
pause();

Answer (score 0):

You mention some exception but I do not see any exception in your question.

When you execute the batch file then the PATH variable is set/changed only for that command session.

If you start new command session then you will not see the changed value.

What it is that you want to achieve by just setting the PATH?

What ever you want to run using java so all that in one batch file/session or set the PATH environment variable manually before running the java command